# Ewan, Ries, and Avut

Tags: word, geography, word-sequence

There is a unique, well-defined word that completes the following quadruple:

> Ewan, Ries, Avut, ????.

What's this word?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "Toba", the last four letters of the other province/territory that meets at [the four corners (60°N, 102°W)](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_corners_(Canada)).
>
> That said, the question says the answer is unique, but there may well be other quadruples of Canadian provinces/territories that make sense and include the three in the question. Perhaps a foursome that produce some natural resource, or a foursome that have population within a certain range, or a foursome whose largest cities have some letter, or…. I haven't checked, but I suspect there's *something*.